# ¿Cómo modifico un .txt dado el texto que se tiene, agregar un salto de línea cada 20 caracteres pero sin romper la palabra, con Python?

Tags: python, txt

Encontré un tutorial donde explicaban algo similar pero opuesto, este ejemplo eliminaba los saltos de línea al final de cada frase.

```
def removerSalto(archivo):
try:
    with open(archivo, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        lineas = f.readlines()

        lineas = list(map(lambda x: x.rstrip('\n'), lineas))

        return lineas
except FileNotFoundError:
    
    print('El archivo especificado no existe.')
resultado = removerSalto('/Desktop/dev.txt')
print(resultado)
```

Ademas encontré que para realizar la comparación de los 20 caracteres una opción es de la siguiente manera, pero esto compara palabras y no sé cómo adecuarlo para que funcione junto y que compare caracteres.

```
function saltoDeLinea(texto) {
let palabras = texto.split(' ');
let contador = 0;
texto = '';
for (let i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++) {
    texto += palabras[i] + ' ';
    contador++;
    if (contador === 3) {
        texto += '<br>';
        contador = 0;
    }
} 
return texto;
}
```

Comment: Veo que ya te respondieron correctamente, sólo te quiero agregar que la 2da función no es Python, creo que es JS, así que dudo mucho que te funcione eso. Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este problema es una oportunidad para mostrar el uso de *[funciones generadoras](https://pywombat.com/articles/generadores-python)*.

Un *generador* es una función que se comporta como un iterador, y que puede ser usada en un `for`. Esta función usa `yield x` en lugar de `return x`, y la diferencia es que sigue ejecutando luego del `yield`.

Primera aproximación:

```
for linea in sig_linea("quij.txt", 20):
    print(linea)
```

En una análisis *top-down*, iniciamos una solución suponiendo un generador `sig_linea()` que lee texto del archivo y lo entrega en líneas de largo máximo 20.

¿Cómo funcionaría `sig_linea()`? Tendrá que leer las líneas originales y dividirlas en palabras, rejuntandolas hasta obtener algo no más largo de 20:

```
def sig_linea(archivo, ancho):
    #   Extrae una línea de ancho dado
    linea = ''
    for trozo in sig_trozo(archivo):
        if len(linea) + len(trozo) > ancho:
            yield linea
            linea = trozo
        else:
            linea += trozo
```

La función `sig_trozo` devuelve una palabra o bien el relleno de blancos que las separada. Si lee la línea

```
la    mona jacinta
```

retornara cinco trozos: `"la", "    ", "mona", " ", "jacinta"`.

La idea es que la salida refleje las separaciones originales en el texto, incluyendo los cambios de línea.

Por cada trozo obtenido, se chequea primero que quepa en la línea en formación. Si no es así, se retorna la línea tal como esta y luego se la reinicializa con el trozo actual.

Para obtener los trozos usamos la expresión regular `(\s+|\S+)`, que es bien simple: reconoce una secuencia de *white-spaces* o de *non-white-spaces*, o sea, palabras.

```
def sig_trozo(archivo):
    #    Extrae una palabra o una secuencia de espacios
    patron = re.compile("(\s+|\S+)")
    with open(archivo, "r") as entrada:
        for linea in entrada:
            m = patron.findall(linea)
            for trozo in m:
                yield trozo
```

#### Demo

```
import re

def sig_trozo(archivo):
    #    Extrae una palabra o una secuencia de espacios
    patron = re.compile("(\s+|\S+)")
    with open(archivo, "r") as entrada:
        for linea in entrada:
            m = patron.findall(linea)
            for trozo in m:
                yield trozo

def sig_linea(archivo, ancho):
    #   Extrae una línea de ancho dado
    linea = ''
    for trozo in sig_trozo(archivo):
        if len(linea) + len(trozo) > ancho:
            yield linea
            linea = trozo
        else:
            linea += trozo

for linea in sig_linea("quij.txt", 20):
    print(linea)
```

**Texto**

> El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha 123456789-123456789-1
> TASA  Yo, Juan Gallo de Andrada, escribano de Cámara del Rey nuestro
> señor, de los que residen en su Consejo, certifico y doy fe que,
> habiendo visto por los señores dél un libro intitulado El ingenioso
> hidalgo de la Mancha, compuesto por Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra,
> tasaron cada pliego del dicho libro a tres maravedís y medio; el cual
> tiene ochenta y tres pliegos, que al dicho

produce:

```
 El ingenioso 
hidalgo don Quijote 
de la Mancha 
123456789-123456789-1
 TASA  Yo, Juan 
Gallo de Andrada, 
escribano de Cámara 
del Rey nuestro 
señor, de los que 
residen en su 
Consejo, certifico y
 doy fe que, 
habiendo visto por 
los señores dél un 
libro intitulado El 
ingenioso hidalgo de
 la Mancha, 
compuesto por Miguel
 de Cervantes 
Saavedra, tasaron 
cada pliego del 
dicho libro a tres 
maravedís y medio; 
el cual tiene 
ochenta y tres 
pliegos, que al 
dicho precio monta
```

Comment: Bastante completa tu respuesta, agregó un tema realmente interesante. Lo estudiaré y pondré en práctica, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4):

No reinventes la rueda. Python trae en su biblioteca estándar montones de módulos y funciones de utilidad. El útil en este caso se llama `textwrap` y hace justamente lo que necesitas. Por defecto asigna valores razonables para todas sus opciones, pero si necesitas cambiar alguna, (por ejemplo, que no divida las palabras-separadas-por-guiones o que no rompa las palabras larguisimasquenocabenenunalinea), mira [la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html)

Un ejemplo de uso:

```
import textwrap
txt = "..."
reformateado = textwrap.fill(txt, width=20)
print(reformateado)
```

El cual produce lo siguiente, si meto como `txt` el texto de esta misma respuesta:

```
No reinventes la
rueda. Python trae
en su biblioteca
estándar montones de
módulos y funciones
de utilidad. El útil
en este caso se
llama textwrap y
hace justamente lo
que necesitas. Por
defecto asigna
valores razonables
para todas sus
opciones, pero si
necesitas cambiar
alguna, (por
ejemplo, que no
divida las palabras-
separadas-por-
guiones o que no
rompa las palabras l
arguisimasquenocaben
enunalinea), mira la
documentación
```

Si hubieras usado los parámetros `break_long_words=False, break_on_hyphens=False` el resultado habría sido:

```
No reinventes la
rueda. Python trae
en su biblioteca
estándar montones de
módulos y funciones
de utilidad. El útil
en este caso se
llama textwrap y
hace justamente lo
que necesitas. Por
defecto asigna
valores razonables
para todas sus
opciones, pero si
necesitas cambiar
alguna, (por
ejemplo, que no
divida las
palabras-separadas-por-guiones
o que no rompa las
palabras
larguisimasquenocabenenunalinea),
mira la
documentación
```

donde, como ves, algunas líneas tienen más de 20 caracteres al no permitir la rotura de palabras que no caben en 20.

Comment: Excelente muchisímas gracias fue de gran utilidad desconocía el modulo textwrap, lo pondré en práctica.